# Predicting Race Results knowing winning probability

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

I would like to model a scenario where I have 4 runners [A, B, C, D] and there chances of winning a race are deemed to be [0.5, 0.3, 0.15, 0.05].

I would like to simulate this race 100 times.

Is it correct that I use Poisson Distribution to calculate the probability of each runner finishing in each of the 4 positions?  But then how do I combine these to produce a simulated Race Result?

I would like to achieve an output in the format of:

```
        [1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th]
Race 1: [ A,   C,   B,   D ]
Race 2: [ B,   A,   C,   D ]
...
```

Comment: The information you're given is insufficient for understanding the probabilities of the runners finishing in 2nd/3rd/4th place. Perhaps D finishes 1st with probability 0.05 but finishes 2nd with probability 0.95. If there is some underlying model that generated those winning probabilities, it's possible it could generate probabilities for all permutations; but that would require additional information.

Comment: @GregMartin I hadn't considered that, my model/scenario does not have that information.  If it is required I would be happy for any answers to include a comment on how this is potentially estimated from the information above or simply how to solve the problem based on any assumed full dataset